# How to use a label on a tableview cell only IF an indexPath object is available

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with two labels in each cell. One shows an object from an array and the other shows the corresponding object from another array created previously.

```
presentArray: [item1, item2, item3]
previousArray: [item1, item2, item3, item4]
```

numberOfRowsInSection returns presentArray.count

In cellForRowAt I need to set one label to display the corresponding index of the previousArray. This is where the crash occurs. The arrays can be different lengths by their nature.

So, how can I tell the tableview cell to display a string from the previous array only IF it exists.

I can presently only display the string in the label if the arrays are the same length, else I get a crash because the indexPath goes out of range, either longer or shorter.

How can I say cell.label.text = "array[indexPath.row]" IF the index path exists.

Comment: If you need such a check then you have a design issue. It would be best for you to update your question showing your `numberOfRowsInSection` method as well as your `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Thank you both, I've updated to show the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before you set the text of the label, you could use an `if` condition like so:

```
if indexPath.row < previousArray.count {
    cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row]
} else {
    cell.label.text = ""
}
```

This code checks to make sure that the indexPath.row of the tableview is less than the number of items in the array, so your code won't crash.

Comment: And you need an `else` to set `text` to some other appropriate value if the condition isn't met since cells get reused.

Comment: @rmaddy Right, unless the OP doesn't need any label text.

Comment: That's exactly why you need an `else`. Cells get reused. A cell may have a text value one time but then later it may be used on a row that doesn't need text do you need to reset `text` in the `else`. Either set it to an empty string or some other appropriate value.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, that's what I meant by not needing any text: an empty string. I'm editing my post.

Comment: What if the array is longer than the indexPath.row?

Comment: btw this works like this:

    if previousArray.count >= presentArray.count {
    cell.previousLabel.text = item[indexPath.row] 
    }else{
    cell.previousLabel.text = "whatever" }

Comment: @Noodybrank I'm confused. Is my answer what you're looking for or not?

Comment: Yes, if the previousArray is shorter than the presentArray. But not if previousArray is longer than the presentArray.

Comment: @Noodybrank Check my updated answer. If the previousArray is longer or shorter, it will work.

Comment: @Noodybrank If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)